# I get the error _tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!button" when I destroy the button

Tags: python, class, oop, object, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
master=Tk()
class check:
def __init__(self,root):
    self.root=root

    self.b1=Button(root,text="Click me",command=self.undo)
    self.b2=Button(root,text="Again",command=self.click)

def click(self):
    self.b1.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.5)

def undo(self):
    self.b1.destroy()
    self.b2.place(relx=0.2,rely=0.2)
c=check(master)
c.click() 
master.mainloop()
```

This is my code. I get `_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!button"` error only when I use destroy method. But I want to delete previous button when another button appears.What should I do?

Comment: You want probably `.place_forget()` instead of `.destroy()`..

Comment: You're placing the button you've already destroyed (self.b1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you doing? When you click the "Click me" button (and call the `self.undo` method, where the self.b1 button is destroyed) and then click the "Again" button (and call the `self.click` method, which tries to place already destroyed self.b1 button), you get the error, that the button does not exist. Of course, it doesn't because you have destroyed it.

It looks like you meant to hide the button. If you intended to do this, then you could just use `.place_forget()` method (there are also `.pack_forget()` and `.grid_forget()` methods for pack and grid window managers, respectively), that hides the widget, but not destroys it, and hence you would be able to restore it again when you need.

Here is your fixed code:

```
from tkinter import *


master = Tk()

class check:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root

        self.b1 = Button(root, text="Click me", command=self.undo)
        self.b2 = Button(root, text="Again", command=self.click)

    def click(self):
        self.b2.place_forget()
        self.b1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5)

    def undo(self):
        self.b1.place_forget()
        self.b2.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.2)

c = check(master)
c.click() 
master.mainloop()
```

I can also give you a piece of advice about the implementation:

1) You should write the code according to the [PEP8 style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/); classes should be named in the [CamelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case).

2) You should inherit your Tkinter app class(es) either from Tk (usage is shown below) Toplevel(the same as Tk, but use ONLY for child windows), Frame class (almost the same as for Tk, but you need to pack/grid/place that Frame in a window).

3) It's better to create the widgets in a separate function (it helps while developing complex and big apps).

4) It's recommended to write `if __name__ == "__main__":` condition before creating the window (if you do like this, you will be able to import this code from other modules, and the window won't open in that case).

Here is an example:

```
from tkinter import *


class Check(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.create_widgets()
        self.click()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.b1 = Button(self, text="Click me", command=self.undo)
        self.b2 = Button(self, text="Again", command=self.click)

    def click(self):
        self.b2.place_forget()
        self.b1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5)

    def undo(self):
        self.b1.place_forget()
        self.b2.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Check().mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

After you destroyed button b1 in the `undo(self)` function tkinter cannot access it anymore and will be confused when you try to place is somewhere in the `click(self)` function.
To make button b1 only disappear visually you could place it outside of the window instead of destroying it.
 To do so replace

```
self.b1.destroy()
```

with

```
self.b1.place(relx=-5, rely=0)
```

This will move the button b1 far to the left, where it cannot be seen.
When calling the `click(self)` function, the button will reappear, because it will be moved inside the window again.

Comment: *This will move the button b1 far to the left, where it cannot be seen* -- NEVER do like that. There is the `.place_forget()` method. so you need to do `self.b1.place_forget()` instead of `self.b1.place(...)`